# Code-Runner Extension Refuses to Use the Correct Environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, miniconda, vscode-code-runner

I'm having a bit of trouble getting code-runner to play nice with my conda environments.

Checklist;

- The correct python interpreter is selected.
- I've explicitly changed the pythonPath and executorMap objects in the settings.json file to the correct environment.
- I've tried reinstalling VSCode, Conda and the Code-Runner extension.

I've run a quick script to check which environment is being used and it confirmed that code-runner insists on using the base environment, rather than the one selected, as shown below.

Just to clarify, the code runs perfectly fine, and shows the correct environment selected when I use Ctrl+F5 instead of code-runner (or when I uninstall code-runner and use the normal run feature), but I'd like for it to work with the extension too.

[image]

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? For now, I have disabled Code Runner.